# groupby by month the data

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataset and i want to do group by month the days. My dataset example;

```
   Date           Price
 2020-01-02       23245
 2020-01-03       23245
 2020-01-04       23245
 2020-01-05       23245
```

I want to this:

```
       Date           Price
     2020-01          252525
     2020-02          4525224
     2020-03          2424552
     2020-04          4552525
```

**So, i want to sum by month while removing days.**

Comment: Please share sample input data. The ones you shared in the answer section is not aligned to what's in the question section

Answer (score 0):

Make sure df has correct types first, then you can group by year, month:

```
df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)
df["Price"] = df.Price.astype(float)
df["year"] = df.Date.dt.year
df["month"] = df.Date.dt.month
df.groupby([df.year, df.month], as_index=False).sum()
```

output:

```
   year  month  Price
0  2020      1  92980
```

Comment: Thank you  for helps. But its not looked YYYY/MM. How can i do that?

Comment: please post *exactly* the form of your data, otherwise it will be difficult to help.  You can use `df.sample(n=20).to_dict()` for example

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume you have a dataframe with one record per day and the price is a random number between 1 and 100, then you can groupby the month and get the sum of price.

```
import pandas as pd
import random
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date':pd.date_range(start='2020-01-01', end='2020-12-30', freq='D'),
                   'Price':[random.randint(1,100) for _ in range(365)]})

df['Month'] = df.Date.dt.strftime('%Y-%m')
print (df)
print (df.groupby('Month')['Price'].sum().reset_index())
```

Here's the output:

```
          Date  Price    Month
0   2020-01-01     13  2020-01
1   2020-01-02     40  2020-01
2   2020-01-03     61  2020-01
3   2020-01-04     86  2020-01
4   2020-01-05    100  2020-01
..         ...    ...      ...
360 2020-12-26     80  2020-12
361 2020-12-27     82  2020-12
362 2020-12-28     13  2020-12
363 2020-12-29     10  2020-12
364 2020-12-30     58  2020-12

[365 rows x 3 columns]
      Month  Price
0   2020-01   1622
1   2020-02   1244
2   2020-03   1564
3   2020-04   1335
4   2020-05   1625
5   2020-06   1545
6   2020-07   1406
7   2020-08   1891
8   2020-09   1625
9   2020-10   1625
10  2020-11   1309
11  2020-12   1327
```

Comment: Yes, i want to that.  Thank you so much.